# Android, Menu in top position?

Tags: android

I followed the guide at:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

And have created an options menu.

But the menu sits at the top right of my app and I want it at the bottom, like a tab menu.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer devices (eg tablets) have the menu in the top-right (like a Pop-up type menu) by default.  Older devices have the menu (like a tabbed menu) on the bottom.  That's just how they are.  My app has the menu on the bottom for my Android 2.2 phone, but on my 4.0 tablet, it's in the top-right.

So, to answer your question - you're not doing anything wrong :).